# How do you remove the gap between NoActionBar and ImageView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, adobe-xd

How do I remove this gap in a ConstraintLayout? The top is an ImageView with a top constraint to the top of the parent (ConstraintLayout).

Gap at the top between the toolbar and banner

[image]

This is how my styles.xml looks like:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

My activity_main.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/headerImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/header" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addlog_btn"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:background="@drawable/newlogbtn"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:onClick="createNewLog"
        android:paddingTop="72sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/headerImg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/headerImg" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addlog_btn2"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/settingsbtn"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:paddingTop="72sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/headerImg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/addlog_btn" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My end goal is this:

[image: End Goal Drawing]

I would like to achieve this with just editing the XML if it is possible, I tried to change the margins and padding's of both parent and I didn't do it right or it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please add your layout xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove this gap by adding `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` to the banner `ImageView` so that it will fill the entire assigned room to it.

So the layout will be after this change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/headerImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/header" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addlog_btn"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:background="@drawable/newlogbtn"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:onClick="createNewLog"
        android:paddingTop="72sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/headerImg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/headerImg" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addlog_btn2"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/settingsbtn"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:paddingTop="72sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/headerImg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/addlog_btn" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @IvanD if you found the answer helpful please accept it by hitting the tick mark at the left.. Thanks